# Help identifying LVDS display connection type

Tags: identification, connector, display, lvds

I have a new motherboard arriving with this connector attached but I need help identifying what display type this LVDS connector uses. I don't think it's MIPI or the standard LVDS but I can't tell.

In the images I have a picture of the board without the port the pin count and what I measured going to ground. The first two I even included resistance is to ground there was maybe one or two others that had a high resistance to ground but not many.

For reference this is from a topway TS-18 Android head unit. I am replacing it with a TS-10 Android head unit.

High-resolution images: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTmTQ.jpg)
Embedded images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Judging from the existence of a 6-pin connector (for capacitive touch, TP - touch panel) and the pairs between ground connections I strongly believe it's an LVDS connector. However, I could count 4 pairs so either the resolution is lower than 1024x768 or I missed a pair. Left-most wide tracks are quite possibly for backlight. Right-most pins (having capacitors around) are quite possibly for logic supply and internal analog unit supplies such as AVDD, VPP, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That connectors is a [Front Flip ZIF FFC socket](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?sm=N&nm=N&bm=K&c=direct_to_board_comp&u=cable_sockets&o=ffc_fpc_sockets&f=ffc_fpc_front_flip_sockets). (My site)

Identifying the connector doesn't tell you anything about how it's used. You would need to do a lot of reverse engineering.

> there is no standard for displays

No. However, there are hints based on what chip they use.

> LVDS

All that says is that it's low voltage digital data. It doesn't say *what* those data are.

LVDS is not a data protocol. It is only a hardware protocol. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling